# `line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'` when run bash `case` function

Tags: bash, syntax-error, case, md5sum

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

deb_folder='/home'


myinstall(){
    deb=$1
    temp="${1%.*}"
    num="${temp##*.}"
    temp2="${temp%.*}"
    method="${temp2##*.}"
    case "$method" in
    md5)
    md5=md5sum $deb
    echo 'here'
    if [[ "${md5:0:3}${md5: -3}" == "$num" ]]; then echo 'correct' else echo $deb'md5 error';false;fi
    ;;
    256)
    sha256=sha256sum $deb
    if [[ "${sha256:0:3}${sha256: -3}" == "$num" ]]; then apt-get install $deb; else echo $deb'sha256 error';false;fi
       ;;
    *) echo $deb'sum type wrong'
       ;;
esac
}

myinstall "${deb_folder}/rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.md5.e596d3.deb"
```

Expect result of above bash script is `correct` or `/home/rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.md5.e596d3.debmd5 error`,but I got `here` after change `md5=md5sum $deb` to `md5=$(md5sum $deb)`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Btw.: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Please don't change your question in ways that invalidate existing answers. Also, when you expected `correct`, you always would get a `here` first, because there is an `echo here` before your `if ...; then echo correct`. Please complete your expected output and actual output.

Comment: @Socowi,after `here`,`if ...; then echo correct else` should output too.why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem 1

Instead of `md5=md5sum $deb` you probably meant `md5=$(md5sum $deb)` or even better `md5=$(md5sum "$deb")`. The same goes for `sha256=sha256sum $deb`.

`md5=$(md5sum $deb)` runs the command `md5sum $deb` and stores its output in the variable `md5`.

`md5=md5sum $deb` runs the "command" `$deb` while setting the environment variable `md5=md5sum` for this command. You may have seen this construct in idioms like `IFS= read -r line` or `LC_ALL=C sort` before.

### Problem 2

The following `if` has only one branch. That `else` is very misleading.

```
if [[ "${md5:0:3}${md5: -3}" == "$num" ]]; then echo 'correct' else echo $deb'md5 error';false;fi
```

If written properly formatted, the problem becomes clear:

```
if [[ "${md5:0:3}${md5: -3}" == "$num" ]]; then
  echo 'correct' else echo $deb'md5 error'
  false
fi
```

Here the `else` is not a keyword, but a simple argument to `echo`. *If* you enter the `if` you would get the output `correct else echo /home/rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.md5.e596d3.debmd5 error`.

To fix this, add a `;` or linebreak before `else`.

You may as well fix the check `"${md5:0:3}${md5: -3}" == "$num"`. I don't think these things will ever be equal. Execute your script with `set -x` to print the values of your variables, then you see the problems.

Comment: Thanks,revised question as your answer.But output is `here`,expect output shoud be `correct` or `/home/rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.md5.e596d3.debmd5 error`